# Jquery ui autocomplete searching words in random order and linking to url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement the jquery-ui autocomplete but with some custom functionality. I am trying to search the label and description and then once selected to go to the url.

I have implemented searching both label and description with words in any order but because of this I cannot seem to reference the item.desc or item.url in _renderItem or in the select function.

I am sure there is something simple I am missing here so any advice would be great.
Thanks in advance.

```
$(function() {

        var adminPages = [
            {
                "label": "Manage pages",
                "desc": "here is some text",
                "url": "/managepages.aspx"                    
            },
            {
                "label": "Manage Navigation",
                "desc": "here is some text",
                "url": "/managenavigation.aspx"
            }
        ];
        //var result = adminPages.map(a => a.label);
        var result = $.map(adminPages, function (n, i) {
            return [[n.label, n.desc]];
        });

        $(".admin-search").autocomplete({
            source: function (requestObj, responseFunc) {
                var matchArry = result.slice(); //-- Copy the array
                var srchTerms = $.trim(requestObj.term).split(/\s+/);

                //--- For each search term, remove non-matches.
                $.each(srchTerms, function (J, term) {
                    var regX = new RegExp(term, "i");
                    matchArry = $.map(matchArry, function (item) {
                        return regX.test(item) ? item : null;
                    });
                });

                //--- Return the match results.
                responseFunc(matchArry);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //window.location = ui.item.url;
            }

        })
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
                .append("<a>" + item.label +
                    "<br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Desc: " + item.desc + "</span>" + 
                    "<br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Url: " + item.url + "</span></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
```

[Code pen example](https://codepen.io/bluelevel/pen/QqYqYx)

Comment: It looks like `matchArry` does not contain the `url` element. Would think you would want to return `adminPages[J]`.

Comment: Hi Twisty, thanks for the comment, I am unsure where this would be implemented though. I have added a code pen link if you have time to have a look and let me know? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing your code pen, I have a suggestion. Personally, I am not a fan of `.map()` so I avoid using it in most cases.

Here is my suggestion:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  var adminPages = [{
    "label": "Pages",
    "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent elit libero, malesuada nec orci viverra, elementum iaculis orci.",
    "url": "#"
  }, {
    "label": "Page categories",
    "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent elit libero, malesuada nec orci viverra, elementum iaculis orci.",
    "url": "#"
  }];

  $.each(adminPages, function(i, val) {
    $("#admin-links").append("<div class='large-8 medium-12 columns'><a href='" + val.url + "'><h2>" + val.label + "</h2></a><p>" + val.desc + "</p></div>");
  });

  $(".admin-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(requestObj, responseFunc) {
      var matchArry = [];
      var srchTerms = $.trim(requestObj.term).split(/\s+/);

      console.log("1 - searching");
      $.each(srchTerms, function(J, term) {
        $.each(adminPages, function(key, val) {
          console.log("Is '" + term + "' in '" + val.label + "'?");
          if (val.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            console.log("Yes.");
            matchArry.push(adminPages[key]);
          }
        })
      });

      //--- Return the match results.
      responseFunc(matchArry);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("2 - selected");
      console.log("Navigating to: " + ui.item.url);
      window.location = ui.item.url;
    }

  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<a>" + item.label +
        "<br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Desc: " + item.desc + "</span>" +
        "<br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Url: " + item.url + "</span></a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qeqymya1/

When passing data back to `responseFunc`, you want to pass an array of object that contain all the elements you desire. Your original code only passed an array, containing the labels that matched.

This solution passes back an array of objects that contain `label`, `desc`, and `url` elements.